# STUN server does not return IP address and Port

Tags: ubuntu, nat

I am just getting started with STUN (for use with WebRTC). I installed STUN client on ubuntu (sudo apt-get install stun). I am sitting behing a NAT. I tried to get my IP address and port using a publicly accessible STUN server, for example:

```
stun stun1.l.google.com:19302
```

I also tried other servers but I always get this:

```
 STUN client version 0.96
 Primary: Firewall  
 Return value is 0x00000b
```

I could not find any explanation on this response... What is the issue? Surprisingly, there is no tag available for STUN or TURN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried like this

```
stunclient stun.l.google.com 19302
```

Comment: stunclient? How do I install stunclient? Not in apt-get or npm install repositories.

Comment: stuntman-client